# Create TextBlock dynamically with hyperlinks

Tags: wpf, xaml, hyperlink, winrt-xaml, stackpanel

what is the best way to create texts with several hyperlinks whereby the hyperlinks can appear at different positions within in the text.

I want to build something like this dynamically in the code-behind file:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="380">
    <TextBlock Padding="0" Margin="0" Foreground="White" FontSize="20">Some random Text</TextBlock>
    <HyperlinkButton VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0" Padding="0" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" Content="Link1" Tapped="RealLink_Tapped" />
    <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="20">Some more random Text</TextBlock>
    <HyperlinkButton VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0" Padding="0" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" Content="Link2" Tapped="RealLink_Tapped" />
    <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="20">Some random Text</TextBlock>
    <HyperlinkButton VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0" Padding="0" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" Content="Link3" Tapped="RealLink_Tapped" />
</StackPanel>
```

But this doesnt work so far. How can I get the Hyperlinks aligned with the TextBlocks, though the fontsize, margin and paddings are the same.
And also, how do I get the line break withn in the stackpanel? At the end it should look like a normal TextBlock (with `TextWrapping="Wrap"`).

EDIT:
It's a Windows Phone 8.1 Project

EDIT#2:
I couldn't get the WrapPanel to work with the WPToolkit, instead I've found something [here](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.de/2014/11/windowsphone-81-now-universalwrappanel.html).

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: what a bout to use  a read-only RichTextBox which can recognize and show Hyperlinks that can be clickable?

Comment: I think thats a good idea, even this topic seems to be very complex... I will have a look and let you know

Comment: Ok. I have some idea how to solve this with the RichTextBox.  Let me know it you are interested.

Comment: @Ilan I've got now a rough understanding about a RichEditBox (I hope you meant that). I can fill it with my content in the code-behind file. However, the problem is to flag the parts which should be marked as hyperlinks. And the next thing is, it's not all about hyperlinks, it's about a little Twitter content box, so there are Hashtags and the @-Twitterhandles as well which are not hyperlinks, so I have to do the linking by my own. I don't know if the RhichEditBox can handle this.
What is your idea regarding the RichTextbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updates #2:**
Here is the possible WinRT version.

**Section 1 - Xaml code(user control), here the WinRtApp is the project where the user control is defined. If you want to use some another ContentTemplate to present your data(like tweets), you should parse your text and add a new model(like a TweetPart) see how I did it with the HyperlinkButton, add new DataTemplate and extend the ContentTemplateSelector.**

```
<UserControl
x:Class="WinRtApp.ComplexTextPresenter"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400" x:Name="This">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HyperlinkDataTemplateKey">
            <HyperlinkButton Margin="0" FontSize="12" CommandParameter="{Binding }" Command="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=OnHyperlinkCommand}" Content="{Binding Path=Content}" Foreground="Blue"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="LiteralDataTemplateKey">
            <TextBlock Margin="0" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Path=Content}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="DataTemplateSelectorKey"
                                  LiteralDataTemplate ="{StaticResource LiteralDataTemplateKey}"
                                  HyperlinkDataTemplate="{StaticResource HyperlinkDataTemplateKey}"/>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Rectangle Fill="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=InputCollection}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DataTemplateSelectorKey}" Margin="5">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

**Section 2 - Xaml's code behind**

```
public sealed partial class ComplexTextPresenter : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Input", typeof(string), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), InputPropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void InputPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var ctrl = dependencyObject as ComplexTextPresenter;
        if(ctrl == null)
            return;
        ctrl.Init();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputCollectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("InputCollection", typeof(ObservableCollection<object>), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<object>)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OnHyperlinkCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("OnHyperlinkCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));



    private IEnumerable<object> GetParsedInput()
    {
        List<BaseInputPart> inputParts = new List<BaseInputPart>();
        var strings = Input.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
        strings.ForEach(s =>
        {
            if (s.IsHyperlink())
            {
                inputParts.Add(new HyperLinkPart { Content = s });
            }
            else
            {
                inputParts.Add(new LiteralPart { Content = s });
            }
        });
        return inputParts.OfType<object>().ToList();
    }

    public string Input
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(InputProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InputProperty, value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<object> InputCollection
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue(InputCollectionProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(InputCollectionProperty, value); }
    }

    public ICommand OnHyperlinkCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(OnHyperlinkCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OnHyperlinkCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        InputCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>(GetParsedInput());
    }

    public ComplexTextPresenter()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public abstract class BaseInputPart
{
    public abstract string Content { get; set; }
}

public class HyperLinkPart : BaseInputPart
{
    public override string Content { get; set; }
}

public class LiteralPart : BaseInputPart
{
    public override string Content { get; set; }
}

public static class StringExtension
{
    #region hyperlink regex region

    private static readonly Regex UrlRegex =
        new Regex(
            @"(?#Protocol)(?:(?:ht|f)tp(?:s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?(?#Username:Password)(?:\w+:\w+@)?(?#Subdomains)(?:(?:[-\w]+\.)+(?#TopLevel Domains)(?:com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|travel|[a-z]{2}))(?#Port)(?::[\d]{1,5})?(?#Directories)(?:(?:(?:/(?:[-\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\d]{2})+)+|/)+|\?|#)?(?#Query)(?:(?:\?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)(?:&amp;(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)*)*(?#Anchor)(?:#(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)?");

    #endregion
    public static bool IsHyperlink(this string word)
    {
        var result = false;
        try
        {
            // First check to make sure the word has at least one of the characters we need to make a hyperlink
            if (word.IndexOfAny(@":.\/".ToCharArray()) != -1)
            {
                if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(word, UriKind.Absolute))
                {
                    // The string is an Absolute URI
                    result = true;
                }
                else if (UrlRegex.IsMatch(word))
                {
                    Uri uri = new Uri(word, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

                    if (!uri.IsAbsoluteUri)
                    {
                        // rebuild it it with http to turn it into an Absolute URI
                        uri = new Uri(@"http://" + word, UriKind.Absolute);
                        result = true;
                    }

                    if (uri.IsAbsoluteUri)
                    {
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Uri wordUri = new Uri(word);

                    // Check to see if URL is a network path
                    if (wordUri.IsUnc || wordUri.IsFile)
                    {
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Updates #4 - Selector code (add as a new class)**

```
public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is HyperLinkPart)
            return HyperlinkDataTemplate;
        if (item is LiteralPart)
            return LiteralDataTemplate;
        return null;
    }

    public DataTemplate LiteralDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate HyperlinkDataTemplate
    { get; set; }
}
```

**How to use - MainPage xaml code**

```
<Page
x:Class="PutHereTheNameOfYourProject.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<ComplexTextPresenter x:Name="ComplexTextPresenter"/>
```

**How to use - MainPage xaml code behind**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        ComplexTextPresenter.Input =
            @"I Love https://www.google.com site. I Love https://www.google.com site. I Love https://www.google.com site. I Love https://www.google.com site. I Love https://www.google.com site. I Love https://www.google.com site. I Love https://www.google.com site.";
        ComplexTextPresenter.OnHyperlinkCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(Execute);
    }

    private void Execute(object o)
    {
       //put here the code that can open browser 
    }
}
```

**Relay command code**

```
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<T> _execute;
    readonly Func<T, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Func<T, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public void RefreshCommand()
    {
        var cec = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (cec != null)
            cec(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null) return true;
        return _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }
}
```

**Updates #3**

1. The WinRt is the name of my project, you need to use the name of your project instead.
2. Create UserControl named ComplexTextPresenter.
3. Replace the UserControl's xaml with the code defined in Section 1.
4. Replace the UserControl's code-behind with the code defined in Section 2.
5. Add the RelayCommand code defined in Section 3 as a class to your project.
6. Read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb514546(v=vs.90).aspx), it is about to how to add a references in XAML.
7. In order to get the Wrappanel in your project, run the next NuGet command in your VS Tools/NuGet Package Manager/Package Manager Console: Install-Package WPtoolkit([taken from here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit)).
8. ***Download [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), it will help you to manage all assembly import related issues.***

Comment: Thank You for this effort. Great. But I'm not sure to fully understand it:
What is this namespace `clr-namespace:DataTemplateProjecytSOHelpAttempt`? I'm having trouble adding it to the project, I dont find anything about it.

If I got it right, I don't need to implement the `INPC-baseOberservable Object`?

And whats this Behaviour? How do I get this added to the project `: Behavior<RichTextBox>`?

Comment: Just to be clear. You really mean RichTextBox, because there is no such element available for WindowsPhone? Only RichTextBlock...

Comment: @Ulpin you should mention the fact of specific platform using in your question.

Comment: @Ulpin let me check it.

Comment: Once again. Thank you for this!!!
I've cant remove the syntax error around `local:MyDataTemplateSelector` control? It should be defined in the `WinRTApp` but can't figure out how this should work. And the same for the `<controls:WrapPanel/>`... It doesnt seem to be in the ` xmlns:controls="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"`

Comment: Thanks for beeing so patient with me. But I've got still the same problems. I think I know how to add a namespace to the project but what is this `MyDataTemplateSelector`. Do I have to refernece it somewhere because I can't find anything in your code. And the wrappanel still doesn't get recognized as part of the imported toolkit,
Another issue is the MainPage.xaml where this part doesn't get recognized `<ComplexTextPresenter x:Name="ComplexTextPresenter"/>`

Comment: @Ulpin please see update #4. there is the data template selector code.

Comment: Thank You so much. Finally, I've got it working! It displays now the InputString in the various styles. Surely Iwill need a few days to make it work to display tweets but this solution does at least 90% of the job. Still some little issues with the WrapPanel and Binding the content string through another UserControl into this UserControl. Great work and I really appreciate your patience with me...

Comment: @Ulpin I'm dlad that you get the idea of how it works, you're welcome.